# How to add weights to items that depend on the size of the group they are in

Tags: r

I have a dataset which looks like this

```
product  material
product1 wheat
product1 water
product1 tomato
product2 milk
product3 basil
product3 garlic
```

And I have this rule which says that if a product is made up of 1 material, that material is 100% of the product. If it is made up of 2 materials, the first material is 60% of the total and the second material is 40% of the total. If a product is made up of 3 materials the first material is 70%, the second 20% and the last 10%. I want to add a column of these weights but I dont know how to solve this. There are more rules up to 5 materials, and the weight needs to be easy to change. In the end I want the data from above to look like this

```
product  material weight
product1 wheat    0.7
product1 water    0.2
product1 tomato   0.1
product2 milk     1
product3 basil    0.6
product3 pizza    0.4
```

This is how I started

```
df = tribble(
  ~product, ~material_type,
  "product1", "wheat",
  "product1", "Water",
  "product1", "tomato",
  "product2", "milk",
  "product3", "basil",
  "product3", "garlic")

df %>% 
  group_by(product) %>% 
  mutate(n = n())

  product  material_type     n
  <chr>    <chr>         <int>
1 product1 wheat             3
2 product1 Water             3
3 product1 tomato            3
4 product2 milk              1
5 product3 basil             2
6 product3 garlic            2
```

Which does give me how many materials there are in each group and from here I am not sure how to get any further and hopefully someone here has a good idea that could help me.

edit:

I tried adding the case_when suggested but it didn't work:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(product) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(weight = case_when(n == 5 ~ c(.4, .3, .1, .1, .1),
                            n== 4 ~ c(.5, .3, .1, .1),
                            n ==3 ~ c(.7, .2, .1),
                            n == 2 ~ c(0.6, 0.4),
                            TRUE ~ 1))

Error: `n == 5 ~ c(0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)`, `n == 4 ~ c(0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1)`, `n == 2 ~ c(0.6, 0.4)` must be length 3 or one, not 5, 4, 2
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace.
```

Comment: You have only 1 distinct material_type per product, so how is the percentage changing

Comment: If it is 4 or 5, then what would be the values

Comment: It doesn't matter what the materials are, their percentage are dependent on how many materials there are in one product. For 4 materials it would be 50%, 30%; 10%, 10% and for 5 materials it would be 40%, 30%, 10%, 10% and 10%.

Comment: so, i guess it is a custom percentage.  In that case, you can have a `case_when` i.e. `case_when(n == 5 ~ c(.4, .3, .1, .1, .1), n== 4  ~ c(.5, .3, .1, .1), n ==3 ~ c(.7, .2, .1), n == 2 ~ c(0.6, 0.4), TRUE ~ 1))`

Comment: @akrun I tried using the case_when but it didn't work. See my edit in the post.

Comment: I think the easiest is the `list` of key/val pair.  Can you please check below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create a key/value `list` and then use the `n()` to extract based on the `name`s of the `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
lst1 <- list(`5` =  c(.4, .3, .1, .1, .1), `4` = c(.5, .3, .1, .1),
        `3` = c(.7, .2, .1), `2` =c(0.6, 0.4), `1` = 1 )

df %>%
     group_by(product) %>%
     summarise(weight = list(lst1[[as.character(n())]])) %>%   
     unnest(c(weight)) %>%
     select(-product) %>% 
     bind_cols(df, .)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  product  material_type weight
#* <chr>    <chr>         <dbl>
#1 product1 wheat           0.7
#2 product1 Water           0.2
#3 product1 tomato          0.1
#4 product2 milk            1  
#5 product3 basil           0.6
#6 product3 garlic          0.4
```

---

Or `unnest` both the 'material_type' and 'weight' and avoid the `bind_cols`

```
df %>% 
   group_by(product) %>% 
   summarise(material_type = list(material_type),
            weight = list(lst1[[as.character(n())]])) %>% 
   unnest(c(material_type, weight))
```

---

Or another option is `if/else`

```
df %>%
   group_by(product) %>%
   mutate(weight = if(n() == 5)  c(.4, .3, .1, .1, .1)
            else if(n() == 4)  c(.5, .3, .1, .1)
            else if(n() == 3) c(.7, .2, .1) 
            else if(n() == 2) c(0.6, 0.4)
            else 1)
```

Comment: This works perfect, thanks! I used the list version because it allowed med to have the weights in one place so I don't need to change it in several places if we decide to change the weights.